# Validate token via ConfirmEmailAsync() that was generated via GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync() on another domain - InvalidToken

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core, token, registration

I have two Asp.Net Core 2.1 applications.

One site on *firstdomain.com* that should be able to create/register/manage accounts for users on that same domain, as well as create/register/manage user accounts on the site at *seconddomain.com*.

**Creating/registering users from *firstdomain.com* to be users on *firstdomain.com*** works flawlessly via -

1. Send email from controller on *firstdomain.com* including token -

`string token = await userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);`

2. The user receives an email with a button that links to a ConfirmEmail page on *firstdomain.com* where the token is validated via -

```
var user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
var result = await userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, HttpUtility.UrlDecode(token));
```

User email is confirmed, they set their password and are logged into the site. on *firstdomain.com*.

**However...**

Creating/registering users from *firstdomain.com* to be users on *seconddomain.com* is handled in the following way -

1. Send email from controller on *firstdomain.com* including token -

`string token = await userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);`

2. The user receives an email with a button that links to a ConfirmEmail page on *seconddomain.com* where the token **is actually marked Invalid** via -

```
var user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
var result = await userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, HttpUtility.UrlDecode(token));
```

**Creating/registering users from *firstdomain.com* to be users on *seconddomain.com* does not work** and the logs show - VerifyUserTokenAsync() failed with purpose: EmailConfirmation for user XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX

Both applications are running on the same server.

**Relevant Startup.cs code**

Both sites use these same settings in their respective Startup.cs -

```
            // aspNet identity setup
            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
            services.AddScoped<ApplicationSignInManager>();
            // access User/Identity
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

            // set the identity config options with our custom helper
            services.Configure<IdentityOptions> 
            (ApplicationConfigHelper.SetIdentityOptions);
    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(ApplicationConfigHelper.SetCookieOptions);
```

**ApplicationConfigHelper.cs**

```
public static class ApplicationConfigHelper
    {
        public static object ActionRequest { get; private set; }

        public static void SetIdentityOptions(IdentityOptions options)
        {
            // password setup
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
            options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
            options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 6;

            // lock out settings
            options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
            options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;

            // user settings 
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;

            // sign in settings
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;
        }

        public static void SetCookieOptions(CookieAuthenticationOptions options)
        {
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1.0);
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
        }
    }
```

**ApplicationUser.cs**

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Enrolled { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Intended to prevent users from spamming the resend invitation email 
        /// link.
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime? InvitationExpirationDate { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want your users to automatically have access to both sites?

The default implementation of token validation uses a per-user random value that will be stored in the database. Are both of your apps storing user information in the same database?

If you don't want to give both apps complete access to the same database, you could implement a replacement `IUserSecurityStampStore` service to keep track of these random user secrets for both sites. Or derive user "secrets" in a deterministic way by hashing some other secret value that both sites already know, however this has other security implications you will need to consider.

You could also replace the `IUserTwoFactorTokenProvider` service to have complete control over how tokens are produced to ensure both sites can generate and validate these tokens.

Or go the OAuth route, and generate some form of bearer tokens from firstdomain, that seconddomain can verify.

Comment: I do not want users to automatically have access to both sites.

Comment: Both apps are storing user information in the same database.

Comment: You should probably update the question to show how your startup code is currently initialising users / identity and token providers. I didn't think the default token providers used any domain based information, but they may be using data protection services.

Comment: Thanks. I'll update the question to include relevant startup code.

Comment: Hey Jeremy, based on your reply, I believe the OAuth route with a bearer token will solve this issue, but I'm unsure of how to implement this between the two sites. I have generated a proper bearer token along with JWT SigningKey/EncryptionKey, but I don't quite understand how to implement. Do you have any resources or advice for making this work cross domain?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

This ended up being the perfect use-case for [JWT.](https://jwt.io/)

Here's how I solved this issue -

From a controller on *firstdomain.com*, when sending a registration link to the user on *seconddomain.com*, I include a JWT as follows -

```
// use a jwt token that can be verified on another domain
   var token = jsonWebTokenService.GetEncryptedToken(new ClaimsIdentity(GetClaimsList(user.Id)), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
```

```
 private IList<Claim> GetClaimsList(string id)
        {
            return new List<Claim>() {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, id),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.UserData, id),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "ROLESTRING")
            };
        }
```

From JsonWebTokenService.cs -

```
public string GetEncryptedToken(ClaimsIdentity subject, TimeSpan timeSpan)
        {
            // setup credentials
            var signingCreds = new SigningCredentials(signatureKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
            var encryptionCreds = new EncryptingCredentials(encryptionKey,
                SecurityAlgorithms.Aes128KW, SecurityAlgorithms.Aes128CbcHmacSha256);

            // claims identity for jwt creation
            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;

            var token = handler.CreateJwtSecurityToken(jwtSettings.Issuer, jwtSettings.Issuer, subject,
                utcNow, utcNow.AddMilliseconds(timeSpan.TotalMilliseconds), utcNow, signingCreds, encryptionCreds);

            return handler.WriteToken(token);
        }
```

*Note - I manually created the signatureKey and encryptionKey with a separate console application I made that utilized secure/tested encryption libraries such as RNGCryptoServiceProvider() and HMACSHA256() and I stored these values securely in Environment Variables on the server for both domains as well as secrets.json for each project.

The registration link is valid for 10 minutes (lifetime of the JWT).

From a controller on *seconddomain.com*, I verify the JWT -

```
            var user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);

            try
            {
                var principal = jsonWebTokenService.ProcessEncryptedToken(code);

                var name = principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name);
                var role = principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Role);

                if (name != user.Id || role != "ROLESTRING")
                    throw new ArgumentException("User not found.");

                user.EmailConfirmed = true;
                await userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
                await signInManager.SignOutAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("CompleteRegistration", new { userId = userId, code = code });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.LogWarning(ex, "Failed to confirm email for {UserId}", userId);
                return BadRequest();
            }
```

Again, from JsonWebTokenService.cs, I validate the JWT -

```
public ClaimsPrincipal ProcessEncryptedToken(string token)
        {
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = signatureKey,
                ValidIssuer = jwtSettings.Issuer,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = jwtSettings.Issuer,
                TokenDecryptionKey = encryptionKey,
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
            };

            // throws exceptions if the token is no longer valid
            return tokenHandler
                .ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out SecurityToken validatedToken);
        }
```

When the token is successfully validated, the user is redirected to complete their registration.

I hope this helps someone else who might be stuck on a similar issue. There is a ton of information on JWTs if you do your research. But, it took me hours to conjure this one up as there was not much info on using JWTs for email registration verification. JWTs are often used for authentication **AFTER** a user has already entered valid credentials on a site. This solution has provided a way for us to validate email registrations across domains as an alternative to the ASP.NET Core Identity UserManager.